# libGDX renders incorrectly on Chromebook windows

Tags: java, libgdx, game-development, chromebook

When a libGDX app is run in a window on a Chromebook, the top of the app is hidden underneath the window's titlebar and the bottom of the window is left empty.

[Chromebook ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15dYW.jpg)

The screenshot above is from the default libGDX app generated by the setup program, without any changes. It's running on the Chromebook emulator ("Large Desktop API 33") in Android Studio as I don't have a physical Chromebook available.

If I check, I can see that there are two resize() calls: the first is for 732x412 (the full size of the window including the titlebar); the second, following immediately afterwards, is for 732x370 (the size of the space below the titlebar).

Can anyone suggest a clean fix for this?